# Missing .Bash Files in ~/

Tags: terminal, macos, bash, homebrew, iterm

While uninstalling/removing home-brew, node, and yeoman...I noted that I don't have a .bashrc or .bash_profile in my home directory. I only have .bash_history present.

Why is this? Is this bad? If it's bad, how can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bad thing. You don't *need* a .bash_profile, but if you want one, simply re-create ~/.bash_profile as an empty file.

~/.bashrc is not sourced by default in OS X.

Comment: Thank you much for that. I thought something went wrong.